# Request.Files missing input='file' on the page after partial update

Tags: file, asp.net-mvc-2, upload, partial

I have an MVC2 page that includes the following
    
    Left Image
    
    
    
    Right Image
    
    
When I save this page, I should be able to look at Request.Files to get the two file referenced.   But the list is empty.
On the other hand, if I look at Request.Form, the two fields (for BackFile and FrontFile) are present.
Now, this portion of the form is part of the form that is partially updated when other selections on the form are made.
When I have had javascript references in such cases, I have had to also update the javascript references whenever I did a partial update of the page.
But there is no javascript reference to the "input" buttons.  Still, I'm wondering if somehow, the "system" is losing the connection between the fields and their buttons and consequently not associating the input fields with files.
I don't know how to get around this.
Specifically is there a way I can proceed by using the values in Request.Form to do the uploads?

Answer (score 0):

First: You cannot use the values from the Request.Form

Second: Did you change the enctype of the form as below:

```
<form action="home/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<input type="file" name="uploader"></input>
<input type="submit" value="Save"></input>
</form>
```

Thrid: I you have a form as above you can create an action method in the controller like below

```
public class HomeController
{
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UploadPictures(int id, HttpPostedFileBase ProductPhotoFileUpload)
        {
          //handle file save
          return View();
        }
}
```

Forth: The partial update should not matter